# save partially rendered image with command line?

Tags: rendering, command-line

I want to render a frame, the image does not need to be 100% rendered, it can be at 40% stop rendering and save through the command line.
How can I do that?

Comment: Why can't you just adjust the camera view and render at a lower quality?